# bad operand types for binary operator >=, -, *

Tags: java

I'm having trouble figuring out how to fix these errors I keep getting for my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Unit02Prog1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        System.out.print("name");
        name = input.next();

        String catagory;
        System.out.print("Catagory");
        catagory = input.next();

        String numWords;
        System.out.print("numWords");
        numWords = input.next();

        int price;

        if (numWords >= 50) {
            price = ((numWords -50) * .08) + 5.00;
            System.out.println("customer:" + name);
            System.out.println("Placed an ad in catagory:" + catagory);
            System.out.println("Ad length is" + numWords + "words, at a price of $" + price);
        }
        else {
            price = numWords * .10;
            System.out.println("customer:" + name);
            System.out.println("Placed an ad in catagory:" + catagory);
            System.out.println("Ad length is" + numWords + "words, at a price of $" + price);
        }

    }
}
```

These are the lines that are getting the same error but with a different symbol at the end

- `if (numWords >= 50) {`

  > bad operand types for binary operator '<='
- `price = ((numWords -50) * .08) + 5.00;`

  > bad operand types for binary operator '-'
- `price = numWords * .10;`

  > bad operand types for binary operator '*'

How can I fix these

Comment: numWords is a String. How can a Text be greater than a number?

Answer (score 1):

your variable `numWords` is string, please parse it to integer first for comparing. Then, update `price` to double as well. Sample code is as per below.

```
    int numWords;
    System.out.print("numWords");
    numWords = input.nextInt();

    double price;

    if (numWords >= 50) {
        price = ((numWords -50) * .08) + 5.00;
        System.out.println("customer:" + name);
        System.out.println("Placed an ad in catagory:" + catagory);
        System.out.println("Ad length is" + numWords + "words, at a price of $" + price);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`numWords` is a `String`, not an `int`. Parse the String to get an int.

```
int num_words = Integer.parseInt(numWords);
```

Answer (score 1):

## What you are doing wrong

```
if (numWords >= 50) {
```

numWords is a string, and `>=` only works on numbers.

## How to fix

You have 2 options for fixing this:

- Read the number in as a String and convert it to a number

  ```
  temp = input.nextLine();
  numWords = Integer.parseInt(temp);
  ```

  This way means you can check manually, and do not need to catch an exception if the number is wrong.
- Read the number in as a number straight away

  ```
  numWords = input.nextInt();
  ```

  This way is less code, but you will need to catch a `NumberFormatException` if the input is not an integer.

## Other notes

- You use `input.next()` a lot, depending on your inputs you may want to use `nextLine` instead
- You may want to use `System.out.printf` to clean up your printing code

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you need parse from string to integer. Here you have an example:

```
String simplenumber= "10";
int num = Integer.parseInt(simplenumber);
```

In your code:

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    String name;
    System.out.print("name");
    name = input.next();

    String catagory;
    System.out.print("Catagory");
    catagory = input.next();

    String numWords;
    System.out.print("numWords");
    numWords = input.next();

    int price;
    int numWordsInt = Integer.parseInt(numWords);

    if (numWordsInt >= 50) {
        price = (int) (((numWordsInt -50) * .08) + 5.00);
        System.out.println("customer:" + name);
        System.out.println("Placed an ad in catagory:" + catagory);
        System.out.println("Ad length is" + numWords + "words, at a price of $" + price);
    }
    else {
        price = (int) (numWordsInt * .10);
        System.out.println("customer:" + name);
        System.out.println("Placed an ad in catagory:" + catagory);
        System.out.println("Ad length is" + numWords + "words, at a price of $" + price);
    }}
```